# GWT. How to get html tag list

Tags: html, json, gwt, jsni

In Javascript, I can write:

```
var circles = document.all.tags("circle");
```

and in circles variable I will have a list of circle tags.

How can I do this in GWT?
I wrote:

```
public final native void getPoints() /*-{
    this.points = $doc.all.tags("circle");
}-*/;

public final native String toJSON() /*-{
    return $wnd.JSON.stringify(this);
}-*/;
```

but when I call `toJSON` method, I have exception.

Comment: InvocationTargetException without any description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [getElementByTagName()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) in [Document](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/index.html?com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html) class.